# how to restrict specific characters in ext js textfield?

Tags: javascript, regex, extjs

how to restrict specific characters(like apostrophe, !, ^ etc) in ext js textfield to enter with key strokes?
I used below code which allows only mentioned characters

```
{
xtype:"textfield",
maskRe: new RegExp("[a-zA-Z1-9_\s@#$&~`]+$"),
allowBlank : false
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To specify restricted characters instead of allowed characters simply prepend a `^` inside the square brackets, which means "any character except...":

```
maskRe: /[^!\^]/
```

(= any character except `!` and `^`)

Also see [this fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/n2b).

Also note that it's not necessary to use operators like `+`, `^` and `$` because the regular expression used with [`maskRe`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-maskRe) is tested against each single character about to be entered, not against the value of the field.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add start of the line `^` anchor so that it would check for an exact string match and also you need to escape the backslash one more time.

```
new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z1-9_\\s@#$&~`]+$")
```

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj for quick reply and also a big thanks for correcting the question in more readable format.

Comment: [Accept an answer which helps you the most.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to vtype properties for the Ext Js component TextField.
[vtype](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-vtype)

Comment: This approach will not prevent the restricted characters from being entered, but rather mark the field invalid if any of them is entered.